# How to access photo library for ipad apps

Tags: ipad

I am facing a problem when I try to access the photo library when developing iPad apps. However, the same code works properly for iPhone dev. The error which is generated is:

```
On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController
```

I am using the following code for iPad development:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
        {
            UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release]; 
        }
```

Comment: What is the error? Give us a little more info to be able to help.

Comment: error which is showing on console is:

Comment: exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'

Comment: In which case as it suggests it will not work on the iPad, you must present it in a Popover Controller. Is there a reason you want it presented modally instead.

Comment: thanks for your view.same code is run at iphone.but in ipad it generate that error.That means ipad not support present modal view controller.instead of it support PopOverController.what you think?

Comment: same code work on iphone.but it crash while run on ipad.i think iphone support presentModalViewController.while ipad support PopOverViewController.what do u think?

Answer (score 0):

Try presenting with a pop over controller in iPad, doesn't support modal view controller

even I encountered the same problem, so tried using pop over controller and it works now :)

```
UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

 popControl = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:picker];

popControl.delegate=self;
[popControl presentPopoverFromRect:browseButton.bounds inView:mainView    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```